# How do I count how many occurrences per week something happens excel?

Tags: excel, date, excel-2013

I am looking at a rather large excel spreadsheet with a long list of dates on it. Each one of these dates marks an error. What I am trying to find out is how many errors occur per week? From there I hope to make a control chart. Thanks so much and please let me know if there are any additional details I need to provide.

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you run into?  `WEEKNUM()` can give you the week number from the date, and then you can use `COUNTIF()` to create your summary, or use a pivot table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Like TMH8885 metioned get week number from each date and then assuming that your dates are in Column `A` and weeknumbers are in column `B` make a table that list numbers from 1 to 52 next to which enter a `COUNTIF(B:B,D2)`(change D2 to cell pointing at correct week number of course).

In the screen shot I was lazy and included only 22 weeks for my table.

[image]

Comment: In case your data rolls into another year, you can modify the "week" column above to have the week number and year like `=WEEKNUM(A1) & " - " & YEAR(A1)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the WEEKNUM function to pull which week of the year the error occurred in.
`=WEEKNUM(your date cell)`
From there you could use a pivot table to pull in the weeks then find the average count of errors.